# My table in Google BigQuery was "not found in location US"

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm dealing with a problem in google's big query, saying that my table is not found in US location.
How do I fix the second part?

there are two parts to this code.
First- I'm creating a table named "**team_one_gkg_urls_per_theme_ranked**".

'''CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `good-project-123.pango.team_one_gkg_urls_per_theme_ranked` OPTIONS( expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP "2020-06-11 00:00:00 UTC",
    description="count of distinct urls per each theme per each electoral period with rank" ) AS
SELECT elections, theme, count_of_distinct_urls,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY elections ORDER BY count_of_distinct_urls DESC) AS rank
FROM `good-project-123.pango.team_one_gkg_urls_per_theme`
ORDER BY elections ASC, rank ASC
;'''

Second - now I'm creating a table named **team_one_top_100_themes_per_elections**, retrieving information from the previous table **team_one_gkg_urls_per_theme_ranked**.

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `good-project-123.pango.team_one_top_100_themes_per_elections` OPTIONS(
    description="Top 100 themes per each electoral campaign" ) AS
SELECT elections, theme, count_of_distinct_urls, rank
FROM `good-project-123.pango.team_one_gkg_urls_per_theme_ranked`
WHERE rank BETWEEN 1 AND 100
ORDER BY elections ASC, rank ASC
;

In this part I get the error "Not found: Table good-project-123:pango.team_one_gkg_urls_per_theme_ranked was not found in location US"

**How do I correct it**???
note: on the dataset, it doesn't show the previously created table **team_one_gkg_urls_per_theme_ranked**.

Comment: Are you using the code you shared inside the BigQuery console or inside a script?

Comment: Are executing the request in a script? Or manually?